# How to exchange data between Objective-C and PHP

Tags: php, objective-c, json, soap

I am playing around with Objective-C and have been looking for a good how-to example to exchange data it and PHP.  JSON?  SOAP?  If anyone knows of a well written example I could hack at, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

When you say exchange data, do you mean over a network connection, between programs or through files?

If you are look to transfer the data over an internet connection (eg. your Objective-C program has/is a web server) then I would personally use JSON as this would allow your Objective-C program to communicate with a javascript web app in future if required as well as the simple php json_encode / json_decode functions.

I would personally say the same applies to other systems, but depending on how you expect this to work something like xml or SOAP may work better.

Edit:

[JSON Framework for Objective-C on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/)

[PHP Manual for JSON (including links on to json_encode and json_decode) functions.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php)

Comment: Ian,

Thanks for the response.  I am looking for transferring over the Internet.  I just found this URL, which was ideally what I had in mind.

http://tempered.mobi/%20

I will check out the URL's you provided.

-Eddie